# How to secure a post for a garden standpipe -- concrete around pipes?

Tags: plumbing, concrete, pipe, landscaping

We're replacing our 70 year old garden standpipe/water column with a new one, which needs to be bolted into concrete. Any suggestions on how to do this without surrounding the new PVC connectors with concrete-- just cover them in insulating foam first? Other ideas? Should we use pavers instead of pouring concrete?

First pic is what the new base will look like, and second pic is the current situation (also pictured is the ancient sprinkler system we're going to cap off).

Thank you!
[image: Base of new standpipe]

[image: Pic of current situation]

Comment: Why do you need to bolt into concrete? Why not something like schedule 80 galvanized pipe? You could even increase the diameter of the pipe to increase its strength against horizontal loads. In my area with non-trivial frost depth, I would be looking into a frost-free hydrant. They've got high thickness galvanized piping.

Comment: Give us more information about your plan. Do you intend to use that steel post to somehow secure the water pipe, like by strapping the pipe to it somehow? Is the pipe intended to come up *through* the post?

Comment: In my location, (Florida), we just drive a 1 inch galvanized pipe into the ground next to the water pipe and strap the 2 together.  Having a new steel column seems like overkill, unless it's part of some decorative feature that you have not indicated.

Comment: Perhaps the OP simply wants a more attractive standpipe support than a ghetto galvanized pipe?

Comment: @popham it is really hard to find attractive-looking hydrants/water columns that are sold in the US, and all of the ones I can find are mounted via bolts to a base (base supplied by you), rather than driven into the ground. We'd like it to look a little nicer (not what we're using, but an example how this can actually look nice: https://www.regentonnenshop.de/documents/image/14/143/143-9000430-3P-Wasserzapfstelle-Natura-granit.jpg). These are common in Europe and Asia, but rare in the US. We live in Seattle so ground doesn't freeze.

Comment: @Jimmy Fix-it, this is effectively a standing faucet, there's an input inside of it. This isn't what we're buying, but there's a picture here of the same hook-up: https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B0CQ27GYCS/ref=ox_sc_act_title_2?smid=A1K7AACOWKEHF9&psc=1. You can also see that the thing itself needs to bolt into a base. So yes, the pipe comes up through the middle of the post, but the post is entirely above ground.

Comment: Maybe I'm overthinking this. Should we just backfill with dirt until it's only the inlet pipe visible, put a barrier around the inlet pipe so that the concrete doesn't actually touch it (e.g., foam insulation), then pour from there so that no concrete gets to the pipes below? Is that safe enough?

Comment: One reservation is that your question's image looks like carbon steel. Keeping that HSS nicely painted sounds like an annoying maintenance problem. I think that rusted structural steel can look lovely, but I maintain a mental model of normal-person aesthetics to avoid burdening people with my idea of "lovely." Your linked Amazon product, in contrast, is built from stainless steel.

Comment: The 6th image from the Amazon product's image carousel demonstrates another problem: How to interface the faucet with the water supply. Installing the post over an existing vertical pipe, it would be difficult to route the water line through a faucet on the side (without cutting a hand-hole at some elevation below the faucet, at least). Have you already thought through this issue?

Comment: @popham the install will be from the bottom, not the side, and we're planning to cut down the existing vertical pipe. Is that what you were thinking? Thanks for your thoughts on the steel! I'll confirm the material of the one we're getting. I don't mind things that look aged, either (naturally aged-- fake aged isn't my jam).

Comment: Is the plan to put a 90 degree fitting at the top of the new water supply line? Then install the HSS over top of the water supply line? Point a threaded outlet of the fitting to align with a hole in the side of the HSS? Thread a hose bib onto the fitting from the outside of the HSS? Reach in through the open top of the HSS with a hand or a tool to hold the fitting against rotation as you thread on the hose bib? Cap the HSS afterward? Use self drilling metal screws or rivet nuts to attach the flange of the hose bib to the HSS?

Comment: In Seattle you might be able to locally source weathering steel (sometimes called Corten). You might look it up (I recall that the railing on the 45th Ave bridge going down to U Village had a weathering steel railing along it adjacent ravine, but I don't know if it survived the retrofit). Regardless of material, you'll get a lot more longevity if you avoid submerging the base plate in soil. It can be nice if the concrete is built a little wide to give the lawn mower a surface to ride along so that there's no grass trimming around the outside of the base.

Comment: How much of the plumbing is getting replaced? Is the post going at the exact location of the old vertical pipe? My instinct is to assemble two new 2 ft galvanized pipes with a threaded 90 degree fitting between them and cast that into the concrete, adapting the inlet line and outlet line to PEX or whatever you're using. Instead, I suppose you could put a sleeve around the outside of the water line to protect it against settlement and abrasion. A chunk of 1-1/2" or 2" PVC pipe sounds like a nice cheap sleeve to hold the concrete back from the water line.

Comment: I like the PVC pipe as a sleeve, that's a really good idea. I think your other questions are about how to actually connect all the pieces, right? My husband is strategizing that piece at home right now (I'm traveling for work in SE Asia), I'll check in with him to see what he came up with.

Comment: A pipe insulation sleeve could also work really well. For a PVC sleeve, I would use backer rod wrapped a few times into a helix shape (with tape at both ends) to get an even space around the water line's circumference.